# Binding Text Property of child element of ComboBoxItem

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have a WPF ComboBox with a static list of people with an image and first name. I am trying to bind the selected FirstName to a db table. The way I am doing it now (obviously wrong) I am only binding the object and hence writing:

System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem

to my db table.

How can I bind the FirstName from the selected ComboBoxItem from the TextBlock.Text property? Is there a way to do this purely in WPF?

```
      <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}">
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Image Source="/Images/Alice.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Alice" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/Bob.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Bob" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

I am saving the changes to the db table on a button click event

```
    private void SaveAndClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bindingView = (BindingListCollectionView)myCollection.View;
        bindingView.CommitEdit();
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code that you are using to handle the selected item changed? You are going to have to have some code-behind to write to the database, as WPF is intended only to be a presentation layer.

Comment: I am not using a selected item changed event. Should I be?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding the comboboxitems, you should use a datatemplate. Then, you should use the SelectedValuePath to select the value based on the FirstName property in your items. Then you can bind to the textbox.

If you want to bind to the textbox in xaml directly, you'll need to name the element (x:Name="myTextBox"). Then, bind your combobox's SelectedValue like so: SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName="myTextBox", Path="Text"}".

In general, I don't think binding a combobox to a textbox is a very good idea.